# Why KernelStack > ThreadCount*16k

Tags: linux, memory, stack, kernel

Why KernelStack > ThreadCount*16k

Every thread has a KernelStack with a size of 16k, so i tried to count the number of threads in the system with

```
[root@docker31 ~]# ps -eT | wc -l
714
```

and got KernelStack from /proc/meminfo with

```
[root@docker31 ~]# cat /proc/meminfo | grep KernelStack
KernelStack:       12640 kB
```

If one thread has 16k kernelstack

the total kernelstack size should be 714*16k=11424k

but the KernelStack from/proc/meminfo is 1216K(76*16k), more than the thread count

What is the 1216K? Is it the Interrupt Stack per CPU?

I searched the sourcecode of 3.10.0-975.el7 and found KernelStack of /proc/meminfo is counted in do_fork->copy_process->dup_task_struct->account_kernel_stack oprerion, so i think it should equal to thread count

but in fact they are not equal, Why?